# Can the real IP address leak using curl via Tor?

Tags: dns, ip, tor, curl

Having seen [[Tor via Python - can the real IP address leak?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/40414/)](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40414/tor-via-python-can-the-real-ip-address-leak) I am no longer sure whether or not using

> curl -L --insecure -C - --socks5 localhost:9150 -H "User-Agent: " check.torproject.org

is as secure as the python version in the linked post

where
`-L` is to follow redirects
`--insecure` is to allow "invalid" HTTPS certificates
`-C -` is to continue downloading from where it left off (in case the download breaks)
`--socks5 localhost:9150` is where the Tor service is running (default port)
`-H "User-Agent: "` is set the user-agent string to {blank}
`check.torproject.org` is the page to download

The IP contained in the response is that of the exit node, but I do not know whether or not rdns (reverse DNS? - mentioned in linked post) is relevant to curl

The question is: Is the command above as secure as that in the linked post?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`--socks5` will use the SOCKS5 protocol for the HTTP connections but the name lookup will still be done using the normal DNS which means that your public IP address can be seen by the external name server you use. To do name lookup through the proxy too you need to use `--socks5-hostname` option.

From the documentation of curl

> --socks5 
>      Use the specified SOCKS5 proxy - but **resolve the host name locally**.
>
> --socks5-hostname 
>                 Use the specified SOCKS5 proxy (and **let the proxy resolve the host name**)

Comment: So I should use `--socks5-hostname localhost:9150` instead?

Comment: @FtDUh7dGg8: exactly

Comment: Do you know if there is any simple way to check if it is actually letting the proxy resolve the host name on a Linux-based OS?

Comment: @FtDUh7dGg8: For one *.onion domains should only be resolvable through the proxy. Also, you could use a [DNS leak test](https://torguard.net/vpn-dns-leak-test.php). Or you could use a packet sniffer like tcpdump and watch for DNS queries.